# windows server 2003, IIS and localhost

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, localhost

I need to work with the localhost from inside the server in order to run things as schedules.

On my workstation with the regular IIS I have 1 webserver with a lot of sites as aliases. In my server I have a website: (example) www.web.com I thought this would work but it didn't: `http://localhost/www.web.com`

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the actual site in the web browser. You don't need to use the HOSTS file or aliases since you're on the actual server.

Seriously though, you should never web browse from a server.

Comment: i'm not... i'm going to have the server use nncron

Answer (score -1):

Check your IIS bindings to make sure the website you want is listening on localhost. To do this, right click on the site, go to Properties.  In the first tab is a box that says "IP Address".  If this is the only site on this server, select "(All Unassigned)".  Click OK.  Now open a browser on the server, and go to http://localhost and you should see your site.

Comment: it is not the only website... and they are all have assigned ip (most of them to the same ip)
so what can i do?

Comment: In the servers hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) find the line that says:

127.0.0.1  localhost

Change it to:

127.0.0.1 www.web.com localhost

Now see if you can access the site from the server.  If not, check the bindings again, and add a new binding for the site that has the IP address, and for the host header www.web.com.